# Symfony2 Aimeos admin site login gives error

Tags: symfony, authentication

I installed the Aimeos 2016 bundle on Symfony 3.1.2. The /list route works but when I go to /admin and try to log in, I get an error:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/admin_check". The route is wrongly configured.

I did not do anything else to the code. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you've set up Symfony authentication exactly like in the example?

```
security:
    providers:
        admin:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: secret, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        aimeos_customer:
            entity: { class: AimeosShopBundle:User, property: username }
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Aimeos\ShopBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1

    firewalls:
        aimeos_admin:
            pattern:   ^/(admin|extadm|jqadm|jsonadm)
            anonymous: ~
            provider: admin
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin
                check_path: /admin_check
        aimeos_myaccount:
            pattern: ^/myaccount
            provider: aimeos_customer
            http_basic:
                realm: "MyAccount"
        main:
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/(extadm|jqadm|jsonadm), roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/myaccount, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The Symfony security framework is quite picky about the configuration an even minor changes will break it

Comment: Thank you. I thought I followed all the steps but I missed something obviously.

Comment: Replaced my security with your - but nothing to change(((